# PHP cURL file from web to another API on the web

Tags: php, rest, curl, zoho

I'm having a problem getting a file from a remote server to another web application using cURL. When I make the cURL request as shown below, I get a response saying: "the request does not contain any file." I have a feeling that it is because I'm trying to send the file as a simple URL string...but I don't know why that would matter, because it's still an active file. I don't know how to get accomplished what I want accomplished.
When I try and make the request in Postman, I try first by passing just the url string, but I get the same "the request does not contain any file" error response, but then when I change the type on the value box from text to file and attach just a random file in Postman, the request works and attaches the file to the endpoint. The problem is, I won't be working with file streams, I'll only be working with URLs to those files, and so I need help moving the URL to where I need it to go. Here is the request as I have it now, **what do I need to do to make the URL pass as an actual file**?

```
    $zohoDealId = $decodedResponse["data"][0]["details"]["id"];
    $curlPost = curl_init("https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Deals/$zohoDealId/Attachments");
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data", "Authorization: $postDetails[post_auth_key]"));
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file" => "@" . realpath($fileToPost)));
    curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $fileResponse = curl_exec($curlPost);
```

Comment: You haven't set `curl_setopt($curlPost, CURLOPT_POST, true)`

Comment: @silkfire just added

Answer (score 0):

You should run the PHP curl call with

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

which should show you the full http conversation.

Then you can compare everything (headers, post data etc) with a successful request made by Postman. Then it should be obvious what the difference is.